# fgl library: node context not providing expected outgoing connections lists with ufold

Tags: haskell

Take the following edges in the `{A,B,C,D,E}` graph:

```
A -> B
C -> D
C -> E
D -> A
```

where the nodes are indexed with an `Int`:

```
-5959232120642455838 -> "A"
-5322791284737046018 -> "B"
6963039171755682694  -> "C"
-5226022365236209258 -> "D"
-5226022365169098782 -> "E"
```

The `ufold` provided by fgl provides a context at each node A, B, C, D and E.

```hs
ufold :: Graph gr => (Context a b -> c -> c) -> c -> gr a b -> c
type Context a b = (Adj b, Node, a, Adj b)
type Adj b = [(b, Node)]
```

Here's a function that generates a `String` showing the current visited node and a list of all of its outgoing connections.

```hs
getOutgoing :: Gr String String -> [String]
getOutgoing myGraph =
  ufold (\(_,_,nodeStr,connsOut) st -> 
      (nodeStr ++ " -> " ++ show (map snd connsOut)) : st)
        [] myGraph
```

For the connections listed above, I would expect this `getOutgoing` to return:

```
A -> [-5322791284737046018]
B -> []
C -> [-5226022365236209258,-5226022365169098782]
D -> [-5959232120642455838]
E -> []
```

However, it returns:

```
A -> [-5322791284737046018]
B -> []
D -> []
E -> []
C -> []
```

This is a complete version:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph
import Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree (Gr)

grEdges :: [LEdge String]
grEdges = [ (-5959232120642455838, -5322791284737046018,"AtoB")
          , (6963039171755682694,  -5226022365236209258,"CtoD")
          , (6963039171755682694,  -5226022365169098782,"CtoE")
          , (-5226022365236209258, -5959232120642455838,"DtoA") ]

grNodes :: [LNode String]
grNodes = [ (-5959232120642455838,"A")
          , (-5322791284737046018,"B")
          , (6963039171755682694,"C")
          , (-5226022365236209258,"D")
          , (-5226022365169098782,"E") ]

getOutgoing :: Gr String String -> [String]
getOutgoing myGraph =
    ufold (\(_,_,nodeStr,connsOut) st ->
       (nodeStr ++ " -> " ++ show (map snd connsOut)) : st)
          [] myGraph

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Expected outgoing connections to nodeIDs:"
  mapM_ putStrLn [ "A -> [-5322791284737046018]"
                 , "B -> []"
                 , "C -> [-5226022365236209258,-5226022365169098782]"
                 , "D -> [-5959232120642455838]"
                 , "E -> []" ]

  putStrLn "Actual outgoing connections to nodeIDs:"
  let gr = mkGraph grNodes grEdges :: Gr String String
  mapM_ putStrLn (getOutgoing gr)
```

So, why for nodes C and D, is `ufold` providing a node context containing an empty list for their outgoing connections?

Comment: You can do e.g. `ufold ((>>) . print) (return ())` to see how the output of `ufold` is constructed exactly. In particular, edges appear exactly once in the list - either as an outgoing edge from the source or an incoming edge to the target (seems almost arbitrary which edges appear where? I'm not sure). You are ignoring those edges which are including as incoming edges, not outgoing edges.

Answer (score 1):

Contexts refer only to nodes that have not yet been visited. (Imagine deleting each node and all edges to/from that node as it is visited.) If you want to see the extra edges, don't ignore the incoming edges (the first field of the four-tuple).